# Deutsche Klassik in originaler Aussprache?

Tags: pronunciation

Im englischsprachigen Raum gibt es seit etwas mehr als zehn Jahren Bestrebungen dazu, englische Klassiker – allen voran Shakespeare – in möglichst originaler Aussprache aufzuführen, vgl. dazu insb. http://originalpronunciation.com/.

Meine Frage: Gibt es ähnliche Bestrebungen auch im deutschsprachigen Raum? Eigentlich sollte es einfacher sein als im englischsprachigen Raum, da einerseits die deutschsprachige Klassik weniger weit zurück liegt und andererseits die Dialekte, die der damaligen Aussprache zugrundeliegen, bis heute sich erhalten haben.

Der offensichtlichste Vorteil einer möglichst originalen Aussprache wäre der, dass viele Reimpaare wieder funktionieren würden, die es in der heutigen norddeutsch geprägten Bühnensprache nicht mehr tun, vgl. z.B. Reimpaare aus Goethes Faust (Goethe sprach sein Deutsch mit frankfurterischer Aussprache) wie *Heide/Geleite, diesen/schliessen, Tage/Sprache, neige/reiche, Floh/Sohn, Mann/getan, Zweifel/Teufel, Höhle/wähle/Seele, fühlen/spielen, Zeichen/beugen* usw. usw.

Comment: Problematische Reime der deutschen Klassiker beruhen oft auf Dialekt (*neige/reiche*) oder Unwissen (*Monsieur/Itzehoe*). Deutschland hat keine dem *great vowel shift* vergleichbare Entwicklung erlebt, deshalb ist die Ausgangslage nicht vergleichbar.

Comment: Jede Aussprache des Deutschen beruht auf einem Dialekt. Die heute verbreitete Aussprache beruht einfach auf einem anderen Dialekt als diejenige, die sich in den Reimen der Klassiker zeigt. Die Ausgangslage mag anders sein als im Englischen, aber es liesse sich der gleiche Effekt erzielen: Wenn Goethe nicht mit niederdeutscher Aussprache aufgeführt würde, sondern mit hessischer, dann würden seine Reime wieder funktionieren (ausgenommen seltene Aussprachefehler wie Schillers /ɪtsəˈheː/ für *Itzehoe* – danke für den Hinweis –, die ich allerdings bei Goethe noch nie angetroffen hätte).

Comment: Da innerhalb von 2 Monaten niemand einen Gegenbeweis erbracht hat, empfehle ich, die Antwort als korrekt zu markieren.

Answer (score 2):

Nein, es sind keine solche Bestrebungen für den deutschsprachigen Raum bekannt. Im Gegenteil, es wird heutzutage eher immer - wenn es gemacht wird - auf modern adaptiert, und das nicht nur sprachlich...